# InvalidDefinitionException occours if ResolvableType is already in the header

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka, jackson-databind

We use spring integration and spring kafka in our project.
After the Update from Spring-boot 3.1.7 to 3.2.1 we got an exception during serialization of the messages.

Given the flow:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow sendToKafkaFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from("sendToKafkaFlow.input")
            .transform(Transformers.toJson()) // 1
           // some more handlers/header enricher 
//        .headerFilter(JsonHeaders.RESOLVABLE_TYPE) // 2
            .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate) //3
                   .topic("someTopic")
            )
            .get();
}
```

Every time we send a message with this flow, we see the Exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType["componentType"]-org.springframework.core.ResolvableType["componentType"])

The transfomer in step (1) will create the *json__resolvableType* header.
Within the outboundChannelAdapter (3) the DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper is used to create the kafka headers. As soon as this mapper will map the resolvableType it will produce the error and will not map this header.

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType["componentType"]->org.springframework.core.ResolvableType["componentType"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1308)
(3) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:948)
(2) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:726)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
(1) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:479)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:318)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectMapper.java:3987)
```

As far as I could see in the debugger, the *componentType* is null and will be replaces by an EmptyInstance (1). This EmptyInstance will also be analysed.
The EmptyInstance itself will again return an EmptyInstance for the componentType (2). This leads to the self-reference. (3)

If we would remove this header (flow 2) the header is missing and the exception is gone.

I tried to to switch of fail-on-self-refenrences within the application.yml

```
spring:   
  jackson:
    serialization:
      fail-on-self-references: false
```

But that is not working.
Unfortunately, we have this kind of pattern quite often (in different applications). (transform, do-something, send-to-kafka). For that reason adding a modification of the HeaderMapper or changes the flow, to do the json serialization within the kafka template is some effort.

Is there anything else, we can try to avoid this *Direct self-reference leading to cycle* Exception for the resolvable type header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test I found out that this is not a new Exception. In past it was "hidden" as debug log.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/a57c319f78438ace4b0be3e89ed3398638e47abd#diff-0b0eca71e2fe3c998d8f8c9fb488081a6b4ef2c62190f2e55b38278e84a1b8dcL297

Since we do not need the RESOLVABLE_TYPE header. We created a DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper ignore these Header.

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper kafkaHeaderMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        return new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper(mapper, "!" + MessageHeaders.ID,
            "!" + MessageHeaders.TIMESTAMP,
            "!" + JsonHeaders.RESOLVABLE_TYPE,
            "*");
    }
```

and inject it to the outboundChannelAdapter

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow sendToKafkaFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("sendToKafkaFlow.input")
            .transform(Transformers.toJson()) 
            .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate) 
                   .topic("someTopic")
                   .headerMapper(defaultKafkaHeaderMapper)
            )
            .get();
    }
```

BUT this solves not the general issue: ResolvableType can not be serialized as json with spring BeanSerializer in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

See this factory instead:

```
  Transformers.toJson(JsonObjectMapper<?, ?> jsonObjectMapper)
```

This way you will be able to inject an `ObjectMapper` auto-configured by Spring Boot.

You also can use `headerEnricher()` to override that `JsonHeaders.RESOLVABLE_TYPE` header with something what is a plain `Class`: `headers.get(JsonHeaders.RESOLVABLE_TYPE, ResolvableType.class).getRawClass()`.

Comment: Hi Artem, 
thanks for your answer. I checked both options. 
'''
 Transformers.toJson(JsonObjectMapper<?, ?> jsonObjectMapper)
'''
The self reference issues happen in the DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper. Therefor it was not directly having any effect. 
The second Option:
'''
headers.get(JsonHeaders.RESOLVABLE_TYPE,ResolvableType.class).getRawClass)
'''
That would change the type of that header and Will lead to issues when, reading that header later in. 

I checked the DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper again and found the reason for my confusion.

Comment: The `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` also can be supplied with an auto-configured `ObjectMapper`. Anyway, we need to understand if you need this header to be passed to Kafka at all.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/a57c319f78438ace4b0be3e89ed3398638e47abd#diff-0b0eca71e2fe3c998d8f8c9fb488081a6b4ef2c62190f2e55b38278e84a1b8dcL297

The Exception also occurred  already in the old Mapper, but it was hidden as debug log and therefore we did't saw it. 

If we create a DefaultKafkaHeader together with the mixIn to ignore the ResolvebleType or just ignore it by configuration within den DefaultHeaderMapper it works. 

fail-on-self-references = false, will lead to an StackOverFlow Exception. 

I guess, it is some bug in serializing the ResolvableType

Comment: If we need this header. No. The *JsonToObjectTransformer* has a method *obtainResolvableTypeFromHeadersIfAny* that will use TYPE_ID as default. 

In our use cases it is enough. I think as long as there is no array, or generic class it will work.

Comment: Then you may convert that `JsonHeaders.RESOLVABLE_TYPE` header into 3 other headers: `JsonHeaders.TYPE_ID`, `JsonHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_ID` and `JsonHeaders.KEY_TYPE_ID` before publishing to Kafka.